# What does a pipe refer to in object oriented coding?

Tags: php, operators

I am new to the world of coding, PHP and object oriented programming. I came across the following line of code and was wondering what the **|** is for as well as when you use it? It looks an OR to me but I thought OR is represented by ||

```
empty($this->contact_country) | empty($this->contact_questcomm) |
```

Comment: Bitwise `or` operator http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: When the intent is a logical OR, I would always use `||`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`|` is bitwise OR; `||` is logical OR. These are operators in the PHP language and have nothing to do with OOP.

It's just a coincidence that bitwise and logical Boolean operators work the same way for Boolean types, as false/true and 0/1 are interchangeable in PHP.

For example, `true & false` is equivalent to `1 & 0`. The result is `0`, which is considered a falsy value in PHP (i.e. is `false` in a Boolean context).

Anyway, you shouldn't ever be using bitwise operators in conditional expressions, unless you're doing bit-shifting calculations within the conditions. Use logical operators, which are *made* for conditional logic, so people won't get confused. Like you, I would definitely replace `|` with `||` in your given code, as `empty()` returns either false or true.

Comment: @BoltClock - I take it a better way to have written would have been to have it as `||`.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks. I have no idea as to what bitwise is nor bit-shifting as yet but guess will touch on that when the need arises.

Comment: @BoltClock - This could be a separate question but out of curiosity, how important is it do develop code using MVC?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: What do you mean by important?

Comment: @BoltClock - When I say important, I mean how crucial is it to develop code using MVC? I know this could be as good as asking how long is a piece of string but I am about to embark on a small project and wanted to know whether MVC is something look at using from the get go or is it something you can look at later should the project grow in size?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Well, I do know that although it's a great pattern to base your architecture on, it's not a hard-and-fast rule to abide by.